# Ideal generated by a finite set of points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to work out some examples to help understand the map between subsets of affine space and ideals of the polynomial ring.

Here is the notation I am using: Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, we define $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] $. Let $\mathbb{A}^n$ be the affine $n$-space over $k$. For a subset $Y\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ we define the $I(Y)=\{f \in A \, | \, f(p)=0 \,\, \forall p \in Y\}$.

I am trying to figure out what happens when $Y=\{a_1,\ldots,a_s\}$.
It is clear that for $Y=\{a\}$, $I(Y)=\{f \in A \, | \, f(a)=0\}=(x_1-a,\ldots,x_n-a)$.
There is a proposition in Hartshorne that states $I(Y_1 \cup Y_2)=I(Y_1)\cap I(Y_2)$. Setting $Y_i=\{a_i\}$ this should help us calculate $I(Y)$.

Is there an easy way to calculate $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_1)\cap(x_1-a_2,\ldots,x_n-a_2)$? Looking at the easier case $(x_1-a,x_2-a)\cap(x_1-b,x_2-b)$ seems to be equal to $((x_1-a)(x_1-b),(x_1-a)(x_2-b),(x_2-a)(x_1-b),(x_2-a)(x_2-b))$.

Comment: If $Y=\{a\}$ then is a non-sense to write $I(Y)=(x_1-a,\ldots,x_n-a)$. Your $a$ is an $n$-tuple, so $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, and thus $I(Y)=(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do $n=2$. Write $I_1=(x-a,y-a)$ and $I_2=(x-b,y-b)$ where $a\ne b$.
Then $I_1+I_2=A=k[x,y]$ as $I_1$ and $I_2$ are distinct and maximal. But $I_1+I_2
=(1)$ entails that $I_1\cap I_2=I_1I_2$. Therefore
$$I_1\cap I_2=((x-a)(x-b),(x-a)(y-b),(y-a)(x-b),(y-a)(y-b)).$$

One can reduce this a bit. Note $x-y=(x-a)-(y-a)\in I_1$ and likewise
$x-y\in I_2$. So
$$I_1\cap I_2=((x-a)(x-b),(x-a)(y-b),(y-a)(x-b),(y-a)(y-b),x-y).$$
Maybe this doesn't seem like progress, but $(x-a)(y-b)\in((x-a)(x-b),x-y)$
so that
$$I_1\cap I_2=((x-a)(x-b),(y-a)(x-b),(y-a)(y-b),x-y).$$
If we continue along this path, we get
$$I_1\cap I_2=((x-a)(x-b),x-y).$$

The systematic method of finding intersections of ideals
in polynomial rings is to use *Groebner bases*.

Comment: I am unsure how to continue with this, can you recommend a book or some place to read about Groebner bases and using it find intersections. Otherwise good answer